# Capture position and rotation of an object relative to another object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, quaternions

I have two identical objects and two cameras. What I'd like to achieve is the following:

1) Capture the position and rotation of Cube A relative to Camera A

2) Transfer that to a Cube B, so that in Camera B (which I cannot move), Cube B looks exactly as Cube A looks in Camera A

I was successful doing that with position with the following code:

```
positionDifference = CubeA.InverseTransformPoint(CameraA.transform.position);
```

To transfer it onto Cube B, I do:

```
cubeBpos = transform.InverseTransformPoint(CubeB.transform.localPosition);      

while ( Mathf.Abs (cubeBpos.x + positionDifference.x) > 0.01f ) {
    if (cubeBpos.x + positionDifference.x > 0) {
        CubeB.transform.position += new Vector3(-0.01f, 0, 0);
    } 
    else if (cubeBpos.x + positionDifference.x < 0) {
        CubeB.transform.position += new Vector3(+0.01f, 0, 0);  
    }
    cubeBpos = transform.InverseTransformPoint(CubeB.transform.position);
}
```

That's clunky, but works. However, when I try to transfer rotations, Cube B starts to pivot around the origin. Interestingly, when I move Cube A in world coordinates, Cube B moves in local, and vice versa. I suspect local-to-world coordinate translation is an issue, but I also think my rotation code is naive. I tried to capture rotation in two ways, first like this:

```
rotationDifference = Quaternion.Inverse(CubeA.transform.rotation) * CameraA.transform.rotation;

CubeB.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Inverse(rotationDifference);
```

Second attempt:

```
rotationDifference = new Vector3(transform.eulerAngles.x, transform.eulerAngles.y, transform.eulerAngles.z);

CubeB.transform.eulerAngles = rotationDifference;
```

Both approaches resulted in weird rotational offsets. I tried using localPosition and localEulerAngles, didn't help.

I'm hoping there's a smarter way to do this :)

EDIT:
Here's a Dropbox [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kjivdth96q3g6qd/AngleDiffTesting.zip?dl=0) to the project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are treating position and rotation separately although they influence each other. Let's put both together and say we have model transforms for the two cameras and the two cubes (represented as homogeneous matrices; assuming column vectors). Then, we want to find the transform for cube B `TCubeB`, such that:

```
TCameraA^-1 * TCubeA = TCameraB^-1 * TCubeB
```

Note that `TCamera` is the model transform of the camera, not the view matrix. If you have the view matrix, simply leave the inverse away.

We can immediately solve for `TCubeB`:

```
TCameraB * TCameraA^-1 * TCubeA = TCubeB
```

I'm not too familiar with the Unity API but it seems like you cannot use transformation matrices directly. So let's split the transformation matrix `T` in a rotational part `R` and a translational part `Tr`:

```
TrCameraB * RCameraB * (TrCameraA  * RCameraA)^-1 * TrCubeA * RCubeA = TrCubeB * RCubeB
TrCameraB * RCameraB * RCameraA^-1 * TrCameraA^-1 * TrCubeA * RCubeA = TrCubeB * RCubeB
```

If we care only about the rotation, we can calculate the respective quaternion by simply doing:

```
QCameraB * QCameraA^-1 * QCubeA = QCubeB
```

The translation becomes a bit more difficult. We need to find the translation transform, such that

```
TrCameraB * RCameraB * RCameraA^-1 * TrCameraA^-1 * TrCubeA * RCubeA * RCubeB^-1 = TrCubeB
```

To find the translation vector, simply multiply the origin to the left-hand side:

```
TrCameraB * RCameraB * RCameraA^-1 * TrCameraA^-1 * TrCubeA * RCubeA * RCubeB^-1 * (0, 0, 0, 1)
```

In pseudo-code, this boils down to (the matrices that appear stand for the respective translation vectors):

```
Vector4 translation = (0, 0, 0, 1)
translation += TrCubeA
translation -= TrCameraA
translation = RCameraA.Inverse().Transform(translation)
translation = RCameraB.Transform(translation)
translation += TrCameraB
```

Again, I barely know the Unity API and it might use some different conventions than I did (conventions in transformation math are especially tricky). But I am sure you can adapt the above derivations if something is not correct.

Comment: Thank you so much Nico! I wasn't sure how to adapt it to Unity, but I ended up with this, it does what I wanted:

      `Vector3 translation = new Vector3(0,0,0);`
  `translation += cubeA.transform.position;`
  `translation -= cameraA.transform.position;`
  `translation = cameraA.transform.InverseTransformPoint(translation);`
  `translation = cameraB.transform.TransformPoint(translation/2);`
  `cubeB.transform.position = translation;`
  `Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.identity;`
  `rotation = Quaternion.Inverse(cameraA.transform.rotation);`
  `cubeB.transform.rotation = rotation;`

Answer (score 0):

Nico's great answer solved my issue, but since code-formatting in the comment section wasn't built for this, here's the code that I wrote for Unity based on Nico's answer:

```
    Vector3 translation = new Vector3(0,0,0);
    translation += cubeA.transform.position;
    translation -= cameraA.transform.position;
    translation = cameraA.transform.InverseTransformPoint(translation);
    translation = cameraB.transform.TransformPoint(translation/2);

    cubeB.transform.position = translation;

    Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.identity;
    rotation = cameraB.transform.rotation * Quaternion.Inverse(cameraA.transform.rotation) * cubeA.transform.rotation;

    cubeB.transform.rotation = rotation;
```

It's not one-to-one, but it achieves what I hoped: If Cube A is stationary and Camera A moves around it, then Cube B moves with respect to Camera B in such a way that Cube A and Cube B always have the exact same position and rotation in relation to their respective cameras.

Comment: I think you should remove the line `translation -= cameraA.transform.position` since this is already part of the following inverse. Maybe this is the reason why you have `translation/2` in the last line? Looks correct, otherwise. You're welcome.